# Best way to implement graceful cancel for running async jobs in java

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

Let's say I have an interface like so for components in my application to run jobs -

```
IJob {
    IResult execute();
    void cancel();
}
```

I want to set up my application so I run these jobs asynchronously.  The expectation is that calling cancel should make execute return immediately with a result indicating it was cancelled.

What's the best way to set this up?  I could just create a Thread object to run it that has additional methods to cancel, but I was also looking at the Future interface which I'm new to.

The problem with FutureTask is the cancel isn't graceful and won't allow me to call job.cancel().  Would it be a good idea to extend FutureTask and implement my own handling of it?

Comment: How is Future "not graceful?"  Multi-threading is hard, trying to change Future's implementation is likely to introduce bugs.

Comment: Ok "not graceful" may not have been the best choice of words.  What I mean is cancel() sends a thread interrupt which doesn't really give me a time to properly call job.cancel().

If i create a FutureTask that calls job.execute() (a blocking call) then how would I handle a cancel request so that I can call job.cancel() ?

Comment: What?  Sorry I don't understand that at all.  You'll have to show us some code that explains why you don't have "time" to do something. (In response to your edit: have `execute()` throw `InterruptedException`.  But the Java `ExecutorService` is a better idea.)

Comment: Also starting a new thread just to block on it's completion is a *TERRIBLE* idea.  You might as well have the original thread just complete the task itself, there's nothing to be gained if all you do is block and wait.  You've stopped one thread and started another in its place.  What's the point?

Comment: I'll try to add more context  ... the environment I'm working on is a plugin architecture, where the plugins provide IJob implementations.  I'd like to avoid the plugin having to know anything about threads or dealing with interruptedexceptions etc.  They just implement execute and cancel.

Comment: The core framework of the application which is running these jobs is also monitoring and reporting on their status (and passing down cancel requests).  So when I want to run a job I need to run it in an async task so that the "main" thread can spin around and update the job status and a keep alive.  So the async task (let's say I use FutureTask) is just taking an IJob and calling execute.  But the main thread will receive cancel requests and push them down to the FutureTask.  But if the FutureTask is just blocking on job.execute(), then I don't really have a place to call job.cancel().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling **IJob.execute()** or **FutureTask.run()** will block the current thread, you need to schudle **IJob** or **FutureTask**.

Scheduling **FutureTask** is the best option, a consumer can call **FutureTask.get()** and wait for the result (even if you call **IJob.cancel()**).

I made a little demostration mocking **IJob** and **IResult**, it uses plain threads for scheduling, in production you should have an **ExecutorService** like previous post example.

As you can see, the main thread can check the status calling **FutureTask.isDone()**, basiclly you are checking if the result is already set. Setted result means that **IJob**'s thread is finished.

You can call **IJob.cancel()** almost anytime for finishing the wrapped **IJob** in **FutureTask**, if the method behaves as like in your comments.

**Mock Job:**

```
public class MockJob implements IJob {

    private boolean cancelled;

    public MockJob() {
    }

    @Override
    public IResult execute() {
        int count = 0;
        while (!cancelled) {
            try {
                count++;
                System.out.println("Mock Job Thread: count = " + count);
                if (count >= 10) {
                    break;
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                cancelled = true;
            }
        }
        return new MockResult(cancelled, count);
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        cancelled = true;
    }
}
```

**Mock Result:**

```
public class MockResult implements IResult {

    private boolean cancelled;
    private int result;

    public MockResult(boolean cancelled, int result) {
        this.cancelled = cancelled;
        this.result = result;
    }

    public boolean isCancelled() {
        return cancelled;
    }

    public int getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Main Class:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Job
        IJob mockJob = new MockJob();

        // Async task
        FutureTask<IResult> asyncTask = new FutureTask<>(mockJob::execute);
        Thread mockJobThread = new Thread(asyncTask);

        // Show result
        Thread showResultThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                IResult result = asyncTask.get();
                MockResult mockResult = (MockResult) result;
                Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
                System.out.println(String.format("%s: isCancelled = %s, result = %d",
                        thread.getName(),
                        mockResult.isCancelled(),
                        mockResult.getResult()
                ));
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                // NO-OP
            }
        });

        // Check status
        Thread monitorThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                while (!asyncTask.isDone()) {
                    Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
                    System.out.println(String.format("%s: asyncTask.isDone = %s",
                            thread.getName(),
                            asyncTask.isDone()
                    ));
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                // NO-OP
            }
            Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
            System.out.println(String.format("%s: asyncTask.isDone = %s",
                    thread.getName(),
                    asyncTask.isDone()
            ));
        });

        // Async cancel
        Thread cancelThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                // Play with this Thread.sleep, set to 15000
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                if (!asyncTask.isDone()) {
                    Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
                    System.out.println(String.format("%s: job.cancel()",
                            thread.getName()
                    ));
                    mockJob.cancel();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                // NO-OP
            }
        });

        monitorThread.start();
        showResultThread.start();
        cancelThread.setDaemon(true);
        cancelThread.start();
        mockJobThread.start();
    }
}
```

**Output (Thread.sleep(5000)):**

```
Thread-2: asyncTask.isDone = false
Thread-0: count = 1
Thread-2: asyncTask.isDone = false
Thread-0: count = 2
Thread-2: asyncTask.isDone = false
Thread-0: count = 3
Thread-2: asyncTask.isDone = false
Thread-0: count = 4
Thread-2: asyncTask.isDone = false
Thread-0: count = 5
Thread-3: job.cancel()
Thread-2: asyncTask.isDone = false
Thread-1: isCancelled = true, result = 5
Thread-2: asyncTask.isDone = true
```

**Output (Thread.sleep(15000)):**

```
Thread-2: asyncTask.isDone = false
Thread-0: count = 1
Thread-2: asyncTask.isDone = false
Thread-0: count = 2
Thread-2: asyncTask.isDone = false
Thread-0: count = 3
Thread-2: asyncTask.isDone = false
Thread-0: count = 4
Thread-2: asyncTask.isDone = false
Thread-0: count = 5
Thread-2: asyncTask.isDone = false
Thread-0: count = 6
Thread-2: asyncTask.isDone = false
Thread-0: count = 7
Thread-2: asyncTask.isDone = false
Thread-0: count = 8
Thread-2: asyncTask.isDone = false
Thread-0: count = 9
Thread-2: asyncTask.isDone = false
Thread-0: count = 10
Thread-1: isCancelled = false, result = 10
Thread-2: asyncTask.isDone = true
```

Comment: Ahhh I didn't consider directly calling job.cancel() from the main thread, which of course I could since it has a handle to it.

Slight wrinkle is that after the plugin job has been ran I need to process the result (basically, write the output), this portion of the job also needs to be cancellable.  I think I can work with this, though...

Answer (score 1):

When you call `cancel` in your task, it will send an interrupt signal to the thread running the task.  Your task will need to periodically check to see if that signal has been sent, and react accordingly when it has:

```
if (Thread.interrupted()) {
    performNecessaryCleanup();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using concurrency, use what the language provides instead of implementing something by hand.

As far as I understand, [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) should be the right tool for you since you can:

- Provide it jobs that will be run asynchronously and could return a result
- Shutdown the executor so that all running jobs are cancelled

Example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    List<Future<IResult>> results = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        results.add(executor.submit(new Job(i))); //start jobs
    }

    executor.shutdownNow(); //attempts to stop all running jobs

    //program flow immediatly continues
}
```

Like @JoeC explained in his answer, the condition to guarantee all jobs to be stopped is that *interruptions* are managed **inside** each job since every threads will be marked as *interrupted* when calling `shutdownNow()`.

```
if (Thread.interrupted()) {
    //return result cancelled
}
```

Comment: The issue is that the IJob implementation is provided by a plugin and ideally should not be concerned with thread interrupts, or anything to do with threads at all really.

Comment: My thought at this point is to extend FutureTask and do a very simple override of cancel() which simply calls super.cancel() and job.cancel().

Comment: @TR1096 Ok but in the end, if the IJob is not concerned with thread interruptions, it **not guaranteed** that an IJob will be cancelled when calling `cancel()` or `shutdownNow()` or any similar method.